# Convert list of strings in line break to separate rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, transpose, line-breaks, google-sheets-formula

I need help to convert a string in a single cell in line breaks to separate rows. I've tried it copying the string in google sheet then paste in excel sheet it works but too tedious to do because there are many records.

#### Input:

cell A1 linebreak format without space

```
Apple

Banana

Grapes
```

#### Output:

```
A1=Apple A2=Banana A3=Grapes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, CHAR(10)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow! Thank you Player0's